# how to open access to PEAR directory in php , CentOs?

Tags: php, centos6

`/home/admin/tmp` is admin admin -rwrw...

`/usr/share/pear/PEAR.php` is admin admin -rwrw...

i removed the `sys_temp_dir` in php.ini file!

```
    Warning: require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/pear/PEAR.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/domain/public_html:/home/admin/tmp) in /home/admin/web/domain/public_html/w/vendor/autoload.php on line 8

Warning: require_once(/usr/share/pear/PEAR.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /home/admin/web/domain/public_html/w/vendor/autoload.php on line 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `open_basedir` in your `php.ini` to include `/usr/share/PEAR`.